# CRM 2011 Plugin - Query records that match a value within an array

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I just discovered this great site and would like to thank everyone in advance for any help.

I am working on a plugin that would update contact's email address where the contact's email matches one of the emails in an array. We use a 3rd party marketing tool for sending out mass email campaigns. We want to take all the soft bounce emails we have and update the CRM and clear the bad email from the system. I have an idea to create a plugin where I declare a string array of all the email addresses that bounced. Then run a query of contacts where the email address matches any one of the values in the array. If it matches I would simple update the email address field. Is something like this possible?

I know how to set up the array and query records but what I can't seem to find an example of is where the query looks for the contact email address to match any one of the values in the array. I only find examples where it looks for a specific value from within the array, like 'contact.emailaddress = "name@email.com"'.

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible yes, but you will have to step through the entire array.

So 1st part: I assume you know how to identify that array inside the plugin.

2nd part: you already know how to query the Contact entity for a specific e-mail address

3rd part: Just repeat the example you found to find contact.emailaddress = "name@email.com" for each item in the array of e-mail addresses you have.

```
foreach (string email in emailAddressArrayFrom3rdPartyTool)
{
    //Query for the contacts that match that e-mail address here
    //Update Contacts so that the e-mail address is removed.
}
```

You can also define a List and populate it with Contacts you want to update it. Then you can call the updates when you have tracked down all the records.

Update: You can also go the Fetch XML route: (more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328117.aspx)

```
string fetch = @"
   <fetch mapping='logical'>
     <entity name='contact'> 
        <attribute name='contactId'/> 
           <filter> 
              <condition attribute='emailaddress' operator='in'>
                    <value>List of Array emails here</value>
                    <value>List of Array emails here</value>
                    <value>List of Array emails here</value>
                </condition>
           </filter> 
     </entity> 
   </fetch> "; 

EntityCollection result = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

foreach (var c in result.Entities)
   {
   System.Console.WriteLine(c.Attributes["name"]);
   }
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more efficient solution. When there are 500 email addresses it wouldn't save much time having to manually type in every email address again in the array to check the values.

I was hoping for something like

var qp = from p in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                                     where p["email"].contains(array[].Value)
                                     select p;

Or something like that.

Comment: ok, so maybe you can try a FetchXML query using the IN Operator? You would have to post process the Array a little but FetchXML would fire only once and give you all the contacts that have e-mails in the IN condition. Here's one link to give you some syntax for it: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fef6bd5-3ac4-4764-a8d7-ed31458923e5/operatorin-fetch-xml-ms-crm-2011?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: I will look into that, thanks. Another idea I just had, perhaps a bit extreme and ridiculous though because we have 43k contacts, is to query all contacts and retrieve the email address and then check if that value is contained in the array and if it is, delete it.

Comment: Yeah I'd avoid that.. if a sandboxed Plugin is a must you are limited when trying to do any set comparison. Now if you wanted to query SQL directly and then post the update in the plugin.. that's a very different game.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any experience with that. I'll give it a Google search and read up. Thanks.

Comment: I think the fetchXML you posted will work. Thank you very much.